# Migration Targets

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Now that we are out of beta could we get some migration targets for questions that are a better fit on other sites? I was thinking it would be good to be able to migrate questions to the RPG site and possibly others such as the chess and poker sites.

Comment: Have you seen a significant number of questions that should have been migrated to other sides, and weren't migrated in a timely manner?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I have not, but I was thinking it might be useful to have now that we are out of beta.

Comment: Migrating questions is the use for those tools. If we're not getting questions that need to be migrated, they won't be useful.

Comment: It's been a pretty long settled thing that while games like chess, poker and go have their own SE site, they are still board and card games and thus on topic for us. There's a lot of overlap between different SE site in general, pretty much the standard is to allow anything to stay where it was asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I want to clarify that a moderator can always migrate a question that needs to be migrated. The purpose of those migration targets is to allow regular users to migrate a question when closing it. That is only really valuable when the volume of questions that need to be migrated to a specific other site is high enough that it is no longer an "exception" that moderators can reasonably handle. I don't see anything close to that volume; I don't think I have seen a single flag for migration in months, so I don't think adding migration targets will be necessary or useful at this time.

In addition, the existence of migration targets, especially to sites whose topic largely overlaps our own, can actually be detrimental. Many questions that can be asked on the Chess or Poker sites can also be asked here, and the existence of a migration target may encourage people to close questions that are on topic here. We already get comments about allowed questions "belonging" on other sites.